# Cannot resolve core::slice::Iter as core::iter::Iterator?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a simple iterator in Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct StackVec<'a, T: 'a> {
    storage: &'a mut [T],
    len: usize,
    _head: usize,
}

impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = core::slice::Iter<'a, T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> core::slice::Iter<'a, T> {
        self.storage.iter()
    }
}
```

However, when trying to compile it, I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, T> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == T`
   --> src/lib.rs:135:13
    |
135 | impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for StackVec<'a, T> {
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found type parameter
    |
    = note: expected type `&T`
               found type `T`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: Could not compile `stack-vec`.
```

There's a couple things that are confusing about this error message. For one, it seems like Rust isn't able to resolve a `core::slice::Iter` as `core::iter::Iterator`. But, `core::slice::Iter` *is* an iterator, right? Why aren't these types matching up?

Secondly, I'm seeing an error around expecting `IntoIterator` to be a reference rather than a type parameter. However, it's *not* a type parameter to begin with. What's that about?

What am I doing wrong here? What's Rust trying to tell me about my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> There's a couple things that are confusing about this error message.

You're dead right, it's quite a hard message to parse.

> it seems like Rust isn't able to resolve a `core::slice::Iter` as `core::iter::Iterator`

You're dead wrong: you mis-parsed the message by missing some angle brackets. (I said it was hard to parse!) Let's look at the message, with some crucial bracketing highlighted:

```
type mismatch resolving `<core::slice::Iter<'_, T> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item == T`
                         (________________________________________________)
```

The problem isn't resolving `core::slice::Iter<'_, T>` as `core::iter::Iterator`, it's resolving the equality, where the whole expression `<core::slice::Iter<'_, T> as core::iter::Iterator>::Item` is the left-hand side. That whole mess names a single type: it's the type you get by using the `as` operator to upcast `core::slice::Iter<'_, T>` to `core::iter::Iterator`, and then take the `Item` member of it.

The trait `IntoIterator` is defined as follows:

```
pub trait IntoIterator where
    <Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item == Self::Item
```

That is, to implement the trait, you need to satisfy the requirement given. This is the requirement the compiler is complaining about. You've defined `Item` as `T`, and `IntoIter` as `core::slice::Iter<'_, T>`, but putting those two definitions in doesn't satisfy the equality.

Put another way, to implement `IntoIterator`, you need to define an `Item` type, it needs to be the same as your underlying iterator's `Item` type. `core::slice::Iter<'a, T>` defines its `Item` type like this:

```
type Item = &'a T
```

so you need the same definition in your `impl` block.

[Here's a Playground with your definition fixed](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ef85938e853a8d0977683e3488ad0bc6&version=stable), and an empty `main()` so it'll compile.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the help! This totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

> For one, it seems like Rust isn't able to resolve a core::slice::Iter as core::iter::Iterator. But, core::slice::Iter is an iterator, right? Why aren't these types matching up?

You're missing the crucial part of the message:

> type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, T> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == T`

It can't resolve it *as an iterator with the `Item` type as `T`.

This is because `slice::Iter` is an iterator over references, not values.

Comment: So, I tried changing my implementation to: `self.storage.into_iter()`, but I'm still seeing the same error message. That should return an iterator of values, rather than references right?

Comment: @bioball your `self.storage` is a mutable reference to data, a slice of some data owned elsewhere. Calling `into_iter` on an `&mut [T]` isn't going to give you an iterator of owned values because you don't own the data to begin with.